# Creating a scanner that holds multiple values

Tags: java

I'm doing a program that has teacher limitations. We are only allowed to use String, NumberFormat, and Scanner classes. My program is asking for car information to plug into a calculator that later will be compared to other cars. My question isn't about the code itself but how you might create an array without using an array function. the information in the 'if' statement 520.2 = total distance in miles, 70 = speed of vehicle, 15 = minutes to fill up gas tank, and $3.59 is the price per gallon. Again i just want to understand how  to hold multiple values in a scanner or if you would do it a different way.

```
int i;
    String make, model;
    double cityMPG, hwyMPG, tanksize, tankdistance = 0, fillups = 0;
    float totalcost = 0; 
    int time = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter your cars make"); //asking for cars make
        make  = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter your cars model"); // asking for cars model
        model = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter your gas tank size"); // asking for gas tank size
        tanksize = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your city MPG"); // asking for City MPG
        cityMPG = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your highway MPG"); // asking for Highway MPG
        hwyMPG = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("if you want to add additional cars press (1)" );
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (i == 1) {
            tankdistance = 520.2 / hwyMPG;
            fillups = (int) ((tankdistance / tanksize));
            time = (int) ((fillups * 15) + (( 520.2 / 70 ) * 60));
            totalcost = (float) ((fillups * tanksize) * 3.59);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please copy-paste the code... Screenshots are just... illogical. We're not doing your work for you, by the way.

Comment: Please no screenshots of code. We like to play with text, not images.

Comment: Create `Car` class and use several instances (1 for each answer + 1 for current car) and do your comparisons on-the-fly.  Hopefully you are allowed to use loops.

Comment: Seriously, please come back to edit your post with the code. As it seems you've abandoned the question and are not seeking an answer.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to edit it right, first post and its my first program for java.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some car object, you will need to keep these cars in an ordered data structure of some type. Either an array or a List will work. Once you have them in this data structure, you can iterate through the items, and make your various comparisons for speed and use cost.

psuedocode:

```
instantiate each car, and store in some data structure called cars

create empty car references for cheap, expensive, fastest, slowest

for each car in cars
  if car faster than fastest
    set fastest = car
  if car slower than slowest
    set slowest = car
  if car cheaper than cheap
    set cheap = car
  if car more expensive that expensive
    set expensive = car
end for loop
```

Now your fastest car is assigned to fastest, your cheapest is assigned to cheap, etc